# stat register in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing a role in ansible that will handle everything about ssl certificates. It's failing when it tries to evaluate the conditional with a variable defined in [`stat`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html).

Looking forward for any explanation and any hacks.

**Part of my tasks**

```
- stat: path={{ ssl_certs_privatekey_path }}
  register: ssl_private_key

- name: Generate a RSA key
  command:
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -days {{ ssl_certs_days }} -subj '{{ ssl_certs_fields }}' -newkey rsa:{{ ssl_certs_key_size }} -out {{ ssl_certs_cert_path }} -keyout {{ ssl_certs_privatekey_path }}
  when: ssl_private_key.stat.exists == false
  tags: ssl-certs
```

Also if I add the debug I can't see its output:

**Debug code?! not working**

```
- debug: msg="Key exists"
  when: ssl_private_key.stat.exists
```

**Error:**

```
TASK: [ssl_certs | Ensure ssl folder exist] ***********************************
ok: [domain.tld]

TASK: [ssl_certs | Generate a RSA key] ****************************************
fatal: [domain.tld] => error while evaluating conditional: ssl_private_key.stat.exists == false

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

The server is running debian stable and I'm running OS X Yosemite with ansible 1.9.4

I already checked google and issues page in the ansible repo on github, [nothing there](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+stat).

Thanks!

**Update:**

Is working with a new isolated playbook:

```
---
- name: "Just for test"
  hosts: my-hosts
  tasks:
  - stat: path=/etc/ssl/certs/cert.key
    register: ssl_private_key

  - debug: msg="Key exists"
    when: ssl_private_key.stat.exists

$ ansible-playbook -i my.inventory --user=radu isolated.playbook                                        

PLAY [Just for test] **********************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [domain.tld]

TASK: [stat path=/etc/ssl/certs/cert.key] *************************************
ok: [domain.tld]

TASK: [debug msg="Key exists"] ************************************************
ok: [domain.tld] => {
    "msg": "Key exists"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
domain.tld                   : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Already tried `when: "ssl_private_key.stat.exists == false"`

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error and could not. Can you start with a totally new isolated playbook with no connection to your existing project and try to reproduce the error? Also do you get any more info in the error message when running with `-v`?

Comment: You are right, is working with a new playbook outside of my directory. I don't get any relevant information using `-v` nor `-vvv`. Thanks. Any suggestions?

Comment: I feel so stupid.. gonna answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel stupid now, but I'm not gonna delete this question or the answer. I think it's a common mistake and everyone should learn from others mistakes :)

The stat wasn't even registered, as I insinuated in my question. It didn't work because I ran the playbook with `--tags` and that task doesn't have one :(

```
$ ansible-playbook -i production-servers.inventory --user=radu --ask-vault-pass --ask-become-pass playbooks/pre_setup_server.playbook --tags "ssl-certs" -v
```

Task:

```
- stat: path={{ ssl_certs_privatekey_path }}
  register: ssl_private_key
```

Peter Lyons suggestion to create a isolated playbook made me realize the problem.

Thank you Peter !